# How to get the attribute of the first child of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables

I have a div

`<div id="img-1" class="cards"><img src="blah" alt="blah2"</div>`

How do I define a variable that has the value of the `alt` attribute, without giving `img` a class or ID?

Thanks!

Comment: [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 const img = document.getElementById('img-1').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
 
 console.log(img.alt);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('img-1').getFirstElementChild.getAttribute('alt');`

You can use `getFirstElementChild`. As you can see it does not matter what your child element is as long as it exists. But if you are looking for alt you can simply query an `img` inside the `div`. `alt` is an image property.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use jQuery to select the div by class then find the first img element and get its alt attribute, then store that to a variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divCards = $('.cards');
    // store the alt attribute of first image to variable
    var attrValue = divCards.find('img').eq(0).attr('alt');
    console.log(attrValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-1" class="cards">
  <img src='blah' alt='blah1'>
  <img src='blah' alt='blah2'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstChild.alt` should do the trick:

```js
const alt = document.querySelector('.cards').firstChild.alt;
console.log(alt);
```

```html
<div id="img-1" class="cards"><img src='blah' alt='blah2'></div>
```

Alternatively you can use the `first-child` CSS selector:

```js
const alt = document.querySelector('.cards > *:first-child').alt;
console.log(alt);
```

```html
<div id="img-1" class="cards"><img src='blah' alt='blah2'></div>
```

Comment: why would you query the classname instead of the id?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var altValue = document.querySelector('.card > img').alt
```

```js
for(var each of document.querySelectorAll('.card > img')){
    var altValue = each.alt;
    ....
}
```

JQuery equivalents

```js
$(`.card > img`).attr('alt')

$(`.card > img`).each(function(index){ // each is bound to this
    var altValue = $(this).attr('alt');
});
```

`>` forces that the `img` tag lies directly below the `.card` element